# Magento - How to filter a product collection using multiple category when flat product/category is on

Tags: magento, flat

First of all, hello to everyone and apologies for my poor English!

I want to filter a product collection using multiple category, this is my code :

```php
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
                        ->addMinimalPrice()
                        ->addFinalPrice()
                        ->addTaxPercents()
                        ->addTierPriceData()
                        ->addUrlRewrite()
                        ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
                        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', $categoryIds);
```

$categoryIds is return array('in'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

It work fine but when I turn on Use Flat Catalog Category/Use Flat Catalog Product it is not work.

Please help me.

------ Edit ----

I print sql by echo $collection->getSelect(). SQL has not "where" condition ??

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, 
`e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, 
`e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, 
`e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`,
`e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, 
`e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, 
`e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, 
`e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`groupdeal_status`, 
`e`.`groupdeal_datetime_from`, `e`.`groupdeal_datetime_to`, `e`.`entity_id`, 
`e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, 
`e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, 
`e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, 
`e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, 
`e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, 
`e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, 
`e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, 
`e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, 
`e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, 
`e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, 
`e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`groupdeal_datetime_from`, 
`e`.`groupdeal_datetime_to`, `e`.`groupdeal_status`, `price_index`.`price`, 
`price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price 
IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), 
price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, 
`price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_category_id`.`category_id` 
FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS 
`price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' 
AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS 
`at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id)
```

Comment: did you successfully reindex data ?

Comment: Yes, i did.I reindex data after turn on Use Flat Catalog Category/Use Flat Catalog Product.

Comment: what is the content of your catalog_product_flat_1 ? is it filled correctly ?

Comment: Thank @Christophe Ferreboeuf.Yes, it is filled correctly.I think joinField() and addAttributeToFilter() does not work when flat-table is enabled.Isn't it ?

Comment: what is groupdeal ? are the columns present in the flat table ?

Comment: Yes,groupdeal_* are colums in flat table. Thoes columns are added by module Devinc Groupdeals.I run above sql by phpmyadmin, it return all row in catalog_product_flat_1.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try to rename 'category_id' by 'cat' for the first variable of the joinField and addattributetofilter?

Comment: I have tried to rename 'category_id' to 'cat' but not effective.
It only changed from "at_category_id" to "at_cat" in sql ( by echo $collection->getSelect() ).

Comment: I solved this problem.The method addAttributeToFilter() in this case seem not working with flat table.
Thank for support,Christophe Ferreboeuf

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, almost the same implementation, solution will be to add where filter to your collection like this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('at_category_id.category_id IN (?)', $arrayCatIds);
```

and to remove current

```
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', $categoryIds);
```

and you are done.